# Is There Any Way to Get NIR Spectral Data from Before Sentinel Satellite Imagery?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to create a raster layer of annual average MSAVI2 values (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/spatial-analyst/msavi.htm, a modified form of NDVI) for each year from 2000 to 2021. To do this, I need both the Near InfraRed (NIR) and red bands found in the Sentinel-2 MSI: MultiSpectral Instrument, Level-1C image collection in order to calculate MSAVI2. The issue is that the sentinel 2 data only goes back to 2015, so I am unable to calculate MSAVI2 for any years prior.

Here's my current setup for calculating a MSAVI2 raster layer for a given year (2018 in this case)

````
```
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2");

//compute composite for all images for a given year
var composite = s2
  .filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-12-31')
  .mosaic()
  .divide(10000)

Map.addLayer(composite, {bands: ['B8', 'B8', 'B4'], min: 0, max: 0.4}, 'composite')

// compute MSAVI2 using expression
var msavi2 = composite.expression(
  '(2 * NIR + 1 - sqrt(pow((2 * NIR + 1), 2) - 8 * (NIR - RED)) ) / 2', 
  {
    'NIR': composite.select('B8'), 
    'RED': composite.select('B4')
  }
);
//add the MSAVI2 layer
Map.addLayer(msavi2, {min: -0.1, max: 0.5}, 'msavi2')
```
````

Is anyone aware of any raster layers in GEE that would have the necessary bands and go back to 2000?